# Pointer is giving unexpected value

Tags: c, pointers, initialization, undefined-behavior

```
void first(){
    int x;
    int *p;
    p= &x;
    scanf("%d",p);
    printf("The value in x or *p is: %d\n",x);
}


void second(){
    int x;
    int *ptr;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("The value in *ptr is: %d\n",*ptr);
}


int main(){
    first();
    second();
}
```

In the above code the `second()` function is miss behaving.What ever value I give for the `x` variable that value is getting assigned to `*ptr` as well as to x. Why?

Comment: Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior. It could print any value.

Comment: In answer to "Why?" printing `*p` shows the value input to `x`: it's undefined behaviour, so the compiler can do anything, and you cannot rely on it... but in this specific case, with this alignment of the planets, probably the compiler just keeps the address of `&x` in a register and reads back from that instead of the invalid `p`. Bluntly: any attempt to read from an uninitialised variable is UB and might do anything, or nothing, or something good, or something bad... etc.

Comment: I know that p in first and the p is second function is different. My question is why *p is in the second function is getting the x value?

Comment: read the comment from `underscore_d` re: undefined behavior.

Comment: @ArturKink: I think you misread the question.

Comment: Change the order of `x`'s and `ptr`'s definition in the 2nd example and re-test. The result probably is different.

Comment: Why not add the input and output of the code? That should make your question clear.

Comment: _"Here's my code that invokes undefined behaviour, here's the behaviour I see on my system, now tell me why"_. Short answer: Nobody can reliably and definitively explain ***undefined*** behaviour in action. All we can say is that it would appear that the uninitialized pointer is pointing to an existing stack variable. Why? Perhaps the vendor thought that to be the safer option? Maybe you just got lucky? Who knows?

Comment: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html), [MSDN - Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633), http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: p points to nowhere, or better, it doesn't even point (-:     so, why would you expect it to "behave"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't assign `p` a value, so it remains uninitialized.  Attempting to dereference that pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Give `p` a value and you'll get the result you expect:

```
int *p = &x;
```

The fact that your code is still printing the correct value is part of that undefined behavior.  One of the ways undefined behavior can manifest is that the code appears to work properly, but then a seemingly unrelated change will cause it to break.

In this particular situation, the functions `first` and `second` each define 2 local variables of the same type and in the same order.  After the call to `first` completes, the memory that contained the values of `x` and `p` from that function still contain those values, but there have been no other function calls yet to overwrite them.

When you then call `second` immediately after `first`.  The variables `x` and `ptr` in `second` end up using the same memory as `x` and `p` in `first`.  And because `ptr` is uninitialized, it still contains the old value which is the address of `x` in first, which happens to be the same as the address of `x` in `second`.

Again, this is undefined behavior, so you can't depend on this happening all the time.  If you added another variable to `first` or called another function between `first` and `second`, that will modify the stack memory previously used by `first`.  Then than memory would contain some other value and you'll probably either print a garbage value or core dump.

The same code may give different results if compiled with a different compiler or different compiler options.  For example, another compiler may choose to put the variables in each function in a different order on the stack, or it could decide to zero out the stack used by a function after the function returns.

Comment: I know that but why content of p is getting the value of x in the second question.

Comment: You can proove this fundamental reasoning by creating a char buffer with a large memory space without initializing it and use GDB to view the memory contents.  There will surely be random values in the buffer every execution.

Comment: @JakePsimos nope; on Linux freshly allocated memory is always zeroed. Other OS may vary, but you will not find random memory left over from other apps on any real OS. (*Reallocated* memory, such as stack memory, is a different story, but is probably the same across all invocations of a basic program.)

Comment: @ams but not when using malloc.

Comment: @JakePsimos Even with malloc; if that memory block has not been used before it will be zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

`int *p=&x;`

The address of x gets stored in p.

`printf("%d",*p);`

Since p has the address of x, *p basically means that you are going to the location specified by p and picking up the item, which is the value of x.